# Exceptions in my iOS Framework Show Private Code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, frameworks, private

I'm building an iOS framework where only a single header file is exposed, and the rest of the code is private. Within Xcode I have all objective-c exception breakpoints on, so normally when there's an exception I'm brought to where it occurred in the code.

During testing in a totally new project that is using this framework I created, every now and then when an exception is raised *inside the framework*, I'm brought to the otherwise private framework code, which is obviously not what I want.

I *think* this may be because the actual raw framework code/project exists in my environment and wouldn't occur for another person using my framework without access to the actual files, but unfortunately I don't have any way to currently test this theory. Does anyone know if this is something I need to be handling in order to truly keep the project files private that I intent to, or is this just a function of having the code exist locally?

Comment: AFAIK, exceptions are meant to show the code in which the exception occurred. You might have noticed that if something in Apple's code crashes, the debugger shows the file, line number and method name in which the exception occurred. This is good, since if it's a bug, users of your framework can report to you on where the crash occurs.

Comment: It may show the file/line number/method name but it doesn't actually open up .m file with all of the code in it - which is what I'm seeing here.

Comment: Opens up? What do you mean by that? If it opens up in Xcode, then it's simply a debugging feature to help you. If it gets logged to the console though… then you have a problem.

Comment: Inside of my project the file I am currently viewing is changed to the .m file from the **private** file inside of the framework with a breakpoint on the line where the exception occurred.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you see please?

Comment: I think maybe I know why you're confused as I wasn't clear about this. I have project A where I'm building the framework - all of the files are there for me to edit but some of the files are private. I build the framework and drop it into project B where only a single header file is public and everything else is hidden inside the framework. I run the application using this framework and an exception occurs somewhere in the private SomeObject.m file, and in Project B where the file isn't 'visible' I am brought to the line where the exception occurred. Does that make any more sense?

Comment: Okay, it does, but I'd still like to see a screenshot please. You can blur out sensitive information if you want.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hbxwwi6wxdjiy8m/Screenshot%202014-08-01%2011.58.08.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58505/discussion-between-mike-and-duci9y).

Comment: So yeah what you're looking at is the project where I'm testing the framework integration. The ...Manager.m file you're looking at is a private file inside the framework itself, but it is being opened inside the test project exposing all of the code.

Comment: @duci9y I was able to test out my alternative theory and my initial hunch was correct. Thanks for your time/help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get in another dev environment with a fresh project to drop in the framework and force an internal framework crash and it appears that if the otherwise private framework files exist on the same environment and a crash occurs when you have objective-c exception breakpoints enabled it will open the private framework file in question, ***BUT*** if you don't have those private framework files (which consumers of your framework wouldn't) you will simply be taken to the normal crash/stack trace view like below:

[image]